# Quantum Monte Carlo: arbitrary Observables in Worm Algorithm

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, computational-physics, greens-functions, spin-models

Consider a generic Hamiltonian of interacting particles on a lattice, where $a^{\dagger}_i$ creates a particle at site $i$, and $n_i=a^{\dagger}_i a_i$ and $\langle i, j\rangle$ are nearest neighbors.

$H=-t\sum_{\langle i, j\rangle}a_i^{\dagger}a_j\ + \sum_{ij}U_{ij}n_i n_j$.

To simulate this system, the Worm Algorithm (https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9703200) works in an extended configuration space where two classes of world line configurations exist: 
(1) Closed world line configurations (no worm present) 
(2) Open world line configurations containing two discontinuities (the Head and Tail of the Worm).

The configurations (1) contribute to computation of thermodynamic quantities such as energy whereas configurations (2) contribute to the Green's function

$G(i,j,\tau_1<\tau_2)=-\frac{1}{Z}tr\big(e^{-\beta H}a_i(\tau_1)a_j^\dagger(\tau_2)\big)$.

My Questions is whether it is possible to compute arbitrary observables using the Worm Algorithm. Say I map a spin 1/2 model to the Hamiltonian above such that
$|\uparrow\rangle_i \rightarrow n_i=1$
$|\downarrow\rangle_i \rightarrow n_i=0$

Obviously I can easily measure the expectation value of magnetization in z-direction $M_z=\sum_i n_i$. But how about the expected magnetization in x-direction?
The Greens function translates to something like $G(i,j,\tau_1<\tau_2)=\langle S_i^-(\tau_1)S_j^+(\tau_2)\rangle$ which is not useful to compute the magnetization in x direction.

Are the only accessible observables those that introduce an even number of discontinuities (integer number of worms) in the World Line configuration?